# How to overcome the threshold 500 ExternalLinks for downloading of the WikipediaData?

Tags: web-access, wikipedia

The command, for instance,

```
WikipediaData["Global warming", "ExternalLinks"]
```

gives me 500 links only, as so as

```
WikipediaData["Global warming", "ExternalLinks", "MaxItems" -> 3000]

Length@%
```

> `500`

But the article "Global warming" contain more than 500 external links (namely 915)

Comment: Looking at the code for the Wikipedia service, this seems like it _should_ be working (the `"continue"` in the Wikipedia API response appears to be handled correctly). I think it may be worth filing a bug report.